# Apache CXF multiple bus definitios

Tags: spring, cxf

I am trying to using CXF with multiples endpoints and 2 bus definitions, here is my configurations:

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="csSegSEndPoint" 
    implementor="#csSegServices"
    address="/ESTSServices" 
    bus="busEST">
</jaxws:endpoint>

<cxf:bus name="busEST">
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="logInbound"/>            
    </cxf:inInterceptors>
    <cxf:outInterceptors>
        <ref bean="logOutbound"/>
    </cxf:outInterceptors>
</cxf:bus>
```

The thing is that when I start the application I get:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'csSegSEndPoint': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)

I did some search and I cannot get what I am doing wrong. Could you please help me?

NOTE: I am using CXF 2.2.10.

salu2..
masch...

Answer (score 1):

This never really worked until CXF 2.4.x sometime.   Definitely upgrade. 2.2.10 is ancient, buggy, unsupported and has a BUNCH of security issues.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your reply, I will try with that version.